# Firebase Database and PHP

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database

I am running into some strange problem with php firebase implementation, i am using ktamas77/firebase-php and i would like to populate the record via a json doc. But it seems every time i try to insert a json doc via

```
$success = $firebase->set(1 . '/AwayTeam/' . '123456', $myJSON);
```

i see a format string in firebase db which looks like this

> "{\"user_id\" : \"jack\", \"text\" : \"Ahoy!\"}"

what am i missing here ?

Comment: $myObj->last = "Miller";
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my earlier request for more info and posted an answer directly instead after looking up the source code of the firebase-php library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [firebase-php sourcecode](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/src/firebaseLib.php#L236) it doesn't accept raw json strings to be entered into the database.
Instead the library will perform a json_encode on whatever you put as $data.

Don't do any decoding/encoding if you want to store PHP objects into the database:

```
$success = $firebase->set(1 . '/AwayTeam/' . '123456', $myObj);
```

In order to insert raw JSON with said library, you'll have to decode it into a PHP object/array first:

```
$success = $firebase->set(1 . '/AwayTeam/' . '123456', json_decode($myJSON));
```

Comment: With the info from your comment, I'd suggest not running any json_* functions at all. You already have a PHP object which you can pass into the set function. (i.e.: instead of $myJSON or json_decode($myJSON) just pass $myObj)

Comment: Edited my answer to show that option as well based on the example code form your question comment.

Comment: Thanks, but the object was just a sample to see why it didnt work, My real json is quite big. I tested it and it works fine